# Installing 32bit wireless driver on amd64

Tags: 32-bit

I have a Dell Latitude 3330 laptop. After updates my wireless stopped working. Found the drivers, deb files. When I try to install using Ubuntu Software Centre, i am getting a message saying wrong architecture amd64. How do I install?
Thanks.
Suparna

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your system uses a broadcom wireless card, and the drivers are available, although not accessible at the moment.  There is a lengthy set of instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx which can guide you through the process of downloading appropriate files and getting them installed on your computer

Comment: Thank you. I did look at the link you have sent. Unfortunately, the instructions are not for the BCM4352 802.11ac. There is post with some deb files but I am not able to install those. Really having a bad time.